# Playing 2 audio simultaneously

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play two audio simultaneously, one of the audio plays background music, while other player plays an audio , both audios are in raw folder. Please any pointer are much appreciated .

Things which i have tried,

*) Create two media player and play the audios in separate media player instances.

*) Playing in separate thread(handler/asynchtask) ,I faced issues when i'm trying to  change/cancel/stop the audio.

*) Soundpool is not suitable since the audio are of large size.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar myself. If you've figured out can you tell us please.